# Calculating patient census by hour

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, census

I am trying to build a query that calculates number of patients in the emergency room by hour.  I have each patients arrival and departure times.  I tried building a boolean style query but all it did was give me the arrivals by hour using this logic

```
SELECT MRN,
   ,CASE WHEN CAST(EDArrival AS TIME) between  '00:00:00.000' and '00:59:59.000' then 1 else 0 end as Hour0
   ,CASE WHEN CAST(EDArrival AS TIME) between  '01:00:00.000' and '01:59:59.000' then 1 else 0 end as Hour1
   ,CASE WHEN CAST(EDArrival AS TIME) between  '02:00:00.000' and '02:59:59.000' then 1 else 0 end as Hour2
FROM EDArrivals
```

WHERE EDArrival between '2012-06-01' and '2013-07-01'

I was thinking maybe the query could place a column for each hour with a 1 or 0 in they were in the ED during those hours.  What I ultimately want to get to is average patients in the ED by hour over the course of a year.  If anyone can think of an easier method I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thank you

Comment: `select count(*) from ... where ... betweeen ... group by hour(edarrival)`, basically, using the sqlserver-specific time stuff.

Comment: Since you are getting departure times and you want patients still in emergency why not just select the patients where departure time is null?

Comment: @jean I can't use that logic as it will just give me those patients that are still in the ED currently.  I need this built as a retrospective tool that can be used to determine when the ED is most full.

Comment: I got it, in that case you can create a 24 rows table with each hour and for each hour return a count from patients in the ED that hour, that can do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create an example of my comment in SQLFiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5234e/6

It's similar to JNK answer (hey, I commented first!)

By the way, creating that table variable will not be great, consider keeping a domain table with the hours.

If do you need performance consider also persisting the date part values. Evaluating them for each row is a performance killer.

Also take care with null departures date times and patients staying at midnight.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't perform great, but it will give the average for each hour over the time span you specify. The perf issue will be because of the function in the `JOIN` criteria in the CTE.  If you need to do this for a very large number of rows it probably makes sense to break that out to another table and populate a column with the hour.

```
DECLARE @Hours TABLE (Hr smallint)

INSERT INTO @Hours
        (Hr)
VALUES
 (0)
,(1)
,(2)
,(3)
,(4)
,(5)
,(6)
,(7)
,(8)
,(9)
,(10)
,(11)
,(12)
,(13)
,(14)
,(15)
,(16)
,(17)
,(18)
,(19)
,(20)
,(21)
,(22)
,(23)

WITH ByDate
AS
(
SELECT 
    CAST(ED.EDArrival AS date) AS 'Dt',h.Hr, COUNT(*) AS 'PatientCount'
FROM
    EDArrivals ED
JOIN
    @Hours AS h
        ON DATEPART(HOUR, ED.EDArrival) = h.Hr
WHERE
    ED.EDArrival BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2013-07-01'
GROUP BY
    CAST(ED.EDArrival AS date) 
    ,h.Hr
)
SELECT
    Hr, AVG(PatientCount)
FROM 
    ByDate
GROUP BY
    hr
ORDER BY
    hr
```

I should also note that though you don't list it in your requirements, it probably makes more sense to also filter on the departure time is >= the given hour.  You likely need to know not just how many patients show up but how many are sticking around at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DateDiff:

```
SELECT DateDiff(n, startdate, enddate) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: thanks but this gives me the patients length of stay in the ED, how could I use this to determine the hours they were actually in the ED without having to manually count each hour?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) [TotalArrivals]
     , DATEPART(hh, [EDArrival]) [Hour]
  FROM [EDArrivals]
 GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, [EDArrival])
```

This will get you the total arrivals grouped by hour. You can then use this to do your averages per hour / whatever other calculations you need. This wont give you the hours with no arrivals, but that should be easy to fit in to your calculations at the end.